# When to use an array vs database

Tags: arrays, database

I'm a student and starting to relearn again the basics of programming.

The problem I stated above starts when I have read some Facebook posts that most of the programmers use arrays in their application and arrays are useful. And I started to realize that I never use arrays in my program.

I read some books but they only show the syntax of array and didn't discuss on when to apply them in creating real world applications. I tried to research this on the Internet but I cannot find any. Do you guys have circumstance when you use arrays. Can you please share it to me so I can have an idea.

Also, to clear my doubts can you please explain to me why arrays are good to store information because database can also store information. When is the right time for me to use database and arrays?

I hope to get a clear answer because I have one remaining semester before the internship and I want to clear my head on this. I do not include any specific programming language because I know most of the programming language have arrays.

I hope to get an answer that can I can easily understand.

Comment: every time you need a container of objects of the same type use an array a list, a collection....

Comment: but why use arrays when database can also store data in the same data type?

Comment: Arrays are good when you need small frequently used data, as it stays in memory and are faster/easy to access. Database have its own overhead and are good to store data permanently.

Comment: Array is data structure to store collection of similar types of elements for execution purpose, you cant persist data permantly in array.

Comment: data base offers more...: query and Persistence... data base will hold data you stored and make it available for you or others even after an app restart

Comment: can you please give me an example in the real world of what data is used frequently that can be stored in an array?

Comment: `I started to realize that I never use arrays in my program` When you start noticing that you use a lot of similar variable names, such as `comment_1`, `comment_2`, `comment_3`, etc, you'll know when to use an array. If you're not working with any dynamic amount of data, you might not need any arrays. It just depends on what you're making and what your program calls for.

Comment: There is overhead associated with storing data into a database: installing the db, configuring it, writing code to read & write data to it, creating schemas, and so forth. Creating an array, on the otherhand, is typically a single line of code. A real world use for an array: anything that would be in a list, like a list of emergency phone numbers, or a list of all the employees who work for a company, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When is the right time for me to use database and arrays?

I can see how databases and arrays may seem like competing solutions to the same problem, but you're comparing apples and oranges.  Arrays are a way to represent structured data *in memory*.  Databases are a tool to store data *on disk* until you need to retrieve it.

The question you pose is kind of like asking: *"When is the right time to use an integer to hold a value, vs a piece of paper?"*  One of them is a structural representation in memory; the other is a storage tool.

> Do you guys have circumstance when you use arrays

In most applications, databases and arrays work together. Applications often retrieve data from a database, and hold it in an array for easy processing.  Here is a simple example:

Google allows you to receive an alert when something of interest is mentioned on the news. Let's call it `the event`.  Many people can be interested in `the event`, so Google needs to keep a list of people to alert.  How?  Probably in a database.

When `the event` occurs, what does Google do?  Well it needs to:

1. Retrieve the list of interested users from the DB and place it in an array
2. Loop through the array and send a notification to each user.

In this example, arrays work really well because users form **a collection of similarly shaped data structures that needs to be put through a similar process**. That's exactly what arrays are for!

Some other common uses of arrays

1. A bank wants to send invoice and payment due reminders at the end of the day. So it retrieves the users with past due payments from the DB, and loops through the users' array sending notifications.
2. An IT admin panel wants to check whether all critical websites in a list are still online. So it loops through the array of domains, pings each one and records the results in a log
3. An educational program wants to perform statistical functions on student test results. So it puts the results in an array to easily perform operations such as `average`, `sum`, `standardDev`...

**Arrays are also awesome at keeping things in a predictable order**. You can be certain that as you loop forward through an array, you encounter values in the order you put them in. If you're trying to simulate a checkout line at the store, the customers in a queue are a perfect candidate to represent in an array because:

1. They are similarly shaped data: each customer has a name, cart contents, wait time, and position in line
2. They will be put through a similar process: each customer needs methods for `enter queue`, `request checkout`, `approve payment`, `reject payment`, `exit queue`
3. Their order should be consistent: When your program executes `next()`, you should expect that the next customer in line will be the one at the register, not some customer from the back of the line.

Trying to store the checkout queue in a database doesn't make sense because we want to actively work with the queue while we run our simulation, so we need data in memory.  The database can hold a historical record of all customers and their checkout outcomes, perhaps for another program to retrieve and use in another way (maybe build customized statistical reports)

Comment: I'm considering using a database instead of  multidimensional arrays of objects, just to be able to use database actions, in my game. So when an android application runs, each database action has to interact with physical memory on the device (on disk?) instead of the RAM memory given to the application? It seems a database would slow a game way down when you're doing hundreds of interactions a second.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different points. Let's me try to explain the simple way:

Array: container objects to keep a fixed number of values. The array is stored in your memory. So it depends on your requirements but when you need a fixed and fast one, just use array.

Database: when you have a relational data or you would like to store it in somewhere and not really worry about the size of the objects. You can store 10, 100, 1000 records to you DB. It's also flexible and you can select/query/update the data flexible. Simple way to use is: have a relational data, large amount and would like to flexible it, use database.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to store data when you have multiple instances of the same type of data.  (For example, say you want to keep information on all the people in your city.  There would be some sort of object to hold the information on each person, and you might want to have a data structure that holds the information on every person.)

Java has two main ways to store multiple instances of data in memory: arrays and `Collections`.

Databases are something different.  The difference between a database and an array or collection, as I see it, are:

1. databases are persistent, i.e. the data will stay around after your program has finished running;
2. databases can be shared between programs, often programs running in all different parts of the world;
3. databases can be extremely large, much, much larger than could fit in your computer's memory.

Arrays and collections, however, are intended only for use by one program as it runs.  Your program may want to keep track of some information in order to do its calculations.  But the data will be in your computer's memory, and therefore other programs on other computers won't be able to access it.  And when your program is done running, the data is gone.  However, since the data is in memory, it's much faster to use it than data in a database, which is stored on some sort of external device.  (This is really an overgeneralization, and doesn't consider things like virtual memory and caching.  But it's good enough for someone learning the basics.)

The Java run time gives you three basic kinds of collections: sets, lists, and maps.  A *set* is an unordered collection of unique elements; you use that when the data doesn't belong in any particular order, and the main operations you want are to see if something is in the set, or return all the data in the set without caring about the order.  A list is ordered, though; the data has a particular order, and provides operations like "get the Nth element" for some number N, and adding to the ends of the list or inserting in a particular place in the list.  A map is unordered like a set, but it also attaches keys to the data, so that you can look for data by giving the key.  (Again, this is an overgeneralization.  Some sets do have order, like `SortedSet`.  And I haven't even gotten into queues, trees, multisets, etc., some of which are in third-party libraries.)

Java provides a `List` type for ordered lists, but there are several ways to implement it.  One is `ArrayList`.  Like all lists, it provides the capability to get the Nth item in the list.  But an `ArrayList` provides this capability faster; under the hood, it's able to go directly to the Nth item.  Some other list implementations don't do that--they have to go through the first, second, etc., items, until they get to the Nth.

An *array* is similar to an `ArrayList`, but it has a different syntax.  For an array `x`, you can get the Nth element by referring to `x[n]`, while for an `ArrayList` you'd say `x.get(n)`.  As far as functionality goes, the biggest difference is that for an array, you have to know how big it is before you create it, while an `ArrayList` can grow.  So you'd want to use an `ArrayList` if you don't know beforehand how big your list will be.  If you do know, then an *array* is a little more efficient, I think.  Although you can probably get by mostly with just `ArrayList`, arrays are still fundamental structures in every computer language.  The implementation of `ArrayList` depends on arrays under the hood, for instance.

Comment: "If you do know, then an array is a little more efficient, I think." Yes, although it varies when it is faster. For the most part, the ArrayList is going to be slower removing; it shifts every Object after the one removed down a position. ArrayLists are internally backed by an array, so the ArrayList has to resize the array by manually copying over the objects when you exceed the array's bounds. Whereas removing in an array, there's just null or a 0 for primitives values. What to use is situational, ultimately it's extremely recommended to use an array when you know the definite size of it.

Comment: Replacing an element with 0 or `null` isn't the same as removing it.  And you can do the same kind of replacement in an `ArrayList`.  Removing an element changes the indexes of everything to the right of the removed element.  Replacing with an "empty" value doesn't.  These are two totally different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an array as a book, and database as library. You can't share the book with others at the same time, but you can share a library. You can't put the entire library in one book, but you can checkout 1 book at a time.